# Gridviews and Generic Lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, datatable

For my current project we have a couple tables that need to be displayed/updated/inserted/deleted/etc.  I'm using a GridView because it makes the most sense to me for the data involved.  So I use LINQ to grab the data out of the DB.  So far, very simple queries...GetAll and GetByID type stuff.
So my queries look like:

```
List<ds_Users_old> selectedUser = DataContext1.ds_Users_olds.ToList();
```

and

```
List<ds_Users_old> selectedUser = DataContext1.ds_Users_olds.Where(user => user.WorkEmail == email).ToList();
```

That sort of thing.

It's pretty easy for me to bind myUsers to a GridView and be done with it.  Except that I also need to sort that GridView by any of the columns.  SortExpression="FirstName", "LastName", "OfficePhone", "UserID", etc.  `myUsers.OrderByDescending(o => o.LastName).ToList();` works just fine but I need  `myUsers.OrderByDescending(o => SortExpression).ToList();` and that doesn’t work.  And I don't want to make a different case for each SortExpression.  From what I have gathered, making that dynamic can get really messy.

So my next thought was to turn my LINQ results into a DataTable in the DAL and just returning the DataTable instead of a generic list of my LINQ object.  DataTables seem to be simpler to sort by dynamic fields.  `dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + mySortDirection;` and the like.  But converting my LINQ results into a DataTable before using them seems a bit bulky to.

Below is a simplified version of my project:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            UsersGridView_BindGridViewData();
        }
    }

    protected void UsersGridView_BindGridViewData()
    {
        List<ds_Users_old>  allUsersList = UserClass.GetAllUsers();
        DataTable allUsersDT = UserClass.GetAllUsersDT();

        //UsersGridView.DataSource = allUsersList;
        //UsersGridView.DataBind();

        UsersGridView.DataSource = allUsersDT;
        UsersGridView.DataBind();
        Session["allUsersDT"] = allUsersDT;
    }

    protected void ComponentGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = Session["testDT"] as DataTable;

        if (dt != null)
        {
            if (e.SortExpression == "GroupName")
                e.SortExpression = "GroupID";

            dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
            UsersGridView.DataSource = Session["allUsersDT"];
            UsersGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private string GetSortDirection(string column)
    {
        string sortDirection = "ASC";
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

        if (sortExpression != null)
        {
            if (sortExpression == column)
            {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "DESC";
                }
            }
        }

        ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

        return sortDirection;
    }
```

And this is the class I access the data with:

```
public static class UserClass
{
    private static nsdc_supplyDataContext DataContext1 = new nsdc_supplyDataContext();

    #region SELECTS
    public static List<ds_Users_old> GetAllUsers()
    {
        List<ds_Users_old> selectedUser = DataContext1.ds_Users_olds.ToList();
        return selectedUser;
    }

    public static DataTable GetAllUsersDT()
    {
        List<ds_Users_old> selectedUser = DataContext1.ds_Users_olds.ToList();
        DataTable selectedUserDT = ConvertToDataTable(selectedUser);
        return selectedUserDT;
    }

    public static List<ds_Users_old> GetUsersByWorkEmail(string email)
    {
        List<ds_Users_old> selectedUser = DataContext1.ds_Users_olds.Where(user => user.WorkEmail == email).ToList();
        return selectedUser;
    }

    public static DataTable GetUsersByWorkEmailDT(string email)
    {
        List<ds_Users_old> selectedUsers = DataContext1.ds_Users_olds.Where(user => user.WorkEmail == email).ToList();
        DataTable selectedUsersDT = ConvertToDataTable(selectedUsers);
        return selectedUsersDT;
    }
    #endregion

    public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

This just seems messy and feel there has to be a more elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a list of objects as your data source, then you need to implement your own sorting logic, like this:

```
public sealed class GenericComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    public enum SortOrder
    {
        Ascending = 0,
        Descending = 1
    }

    private string sortColumn;
    private SortOrder sortingOrder;

    public string SortColumn
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sortColumn;
        }
    }

    public SortOrder SortingOrder
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sortingOrder;
        }
    }

    public GenericComparer(string theSortColumn, SortOrder theSortingOrder)
    {
        this.sortColumn = theSortColumn;
        this.sortingOrder = theSortingOrder;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        PropertyInfo thePropertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(this.sortColumn);
        IComparable object1 = (IComparable)thePropertyInfo.GetValue(x, null);
        IComparable object2 = (IComparable)thePropertyInfo.GetValue(y, null);
        if (this.sortingOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            return object1.CompareTo(object2);
        }
        else
        {
            return object2.CompareTo(object1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your call to `.Sort()` method on your list of objects, you pass a new instance of this helper class (passing it the property of your list you want to sort by and the direction you want to sort - ascending or descending).

Since the comparer logic above uses generics, you can pass whatever type you want to sort by (i.e. `int`, `DateTime`, or even domain objects).

Comment: That did the trick.  Still seems like an awfully bulky solution for such a simple problem but it's the most elegant I've seen so far.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jeremy - yeah, I wish there was a simpler solution too, but the good news is that you can re-use this as a utility class across your web application if you choose to do so. Glad it helped. Feel free to up-vote this answer as well. :-)